# Multiscale Morphological Image Simplification in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, morphological-analysis, mathematical-morphology, multiscaleimage

Hi all I am currently trying to use the SMMT operator of the paper "Multiscale Morphological Image Simplification" at [Dorini](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-85920-8_51#page-1). Since the page cannot be accessed without subscription, I am posting the relevant details here:

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Please Note that I am posting parts of the relevant article as images. I do not know how to write equations in stackoverflow.com**. I want to use this SMMT operator as a pre-processing step in image processing. The code that I have written down is given below:

```
clc;clear all;close all;
tic
I=imread('handwritten.jpg');
I=I(:,:,1);

dim=11 ;
HEIGHT=zeros(dim,dim);
sigma=1/10;
for i=-floor(dim/2):floor(dim/2)
    for j=-floor(dim/2):floor(dim/2)
       HEIGHT(i+ceil(dim/2),j+ceil(dim/2))=-(1/sigma).*max(abs(i),abs(j));
    end
end
NHOOD=ones(dim,dim);
se = strel('arbitrary',NHOOD,HEIGHT);
se

IM1 = imdilate(I,se,'same');
IM2 = imerode(I,se,'same');
figure;
subplot(2,2,1),imshow(I)
subplot(2,2,2),imshow(IM1)
subplot(2,2,3),imshow(IM2)

II = I;
for i=1:1
    phi1 = imdilate(II,se,'same');
    phi2 = imerode(II,se,'same');
    for j=1:size(I,1)
        for k=1:size(I,2)
            if ((phi1(j,k)-II(j,k))<(II(j,k)-phi2(j,k)))
                II(j,k) = phi1(j,k);
            elseif ((phi1(j,k)-II(j,k))==(II(j,k)-phi2(j,k)))                
                II(j,k) = II(j,k);
            else
                II(j,k) = phi1(j,k);
            end
        end
    end
end
IM3=II;
subplot(2,2,4),imagesc(IM3,[0 255]);colormap('gray');axis off;
toc
```

**The result of the code** should be something like this : (again from paper): 
[image].

My result is this:-  [image].

Is my implementation correct?? Can it be improved further ?? Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks in advance for your help guys!! **For more details refer to [Dorini Free Access](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=dMKfo4K7OJYC&pg=PA285&lpg=PA285&dq=self%20dual%20multiscale%20morphological%20toggle%20operator&source=bl&ots=0iAGDvagjR&sig=q-Gdl5QQxfiff9nVUcU0KC1UF2U&hl=en&sa=X&ei=x8GFUonpJYWPrQey5oCwDw&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=self%20dual%20multiscale%20morphological%20toggle%20operator&f=false)**

Comment: why do you think your implementation is not correct? do you have a **specific** problem/question? SO is not for code review. You might consider posting at: http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for code review and more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The implementations looks ok globally, a small clarification though:

```
if ((phi1(j,k)-II(j,k))<(II(j,k)-phi2(j,k)))
                II(j,k) = phi1(j,k);
```

I guess here you would like to change the image value in variable `II` while comparing `phi1` and `I`:

```
if ((phi1(j,k)-I(j,k))<(I(j,k)-phi2(j,k)))
                II(j,k) = phi1(j,k);
```